# On FACEBOOK ios app can't got "push notification" via sent apprequests?

Tags: facebook, push-notification, apprequests

In my app, I can send the apprequests to my friends via FB api, and they can receive the Notification on iOS Facebook app. But here is a difference between "apprequest" and "postToWall". If I posted to my friend's wall something via Web, my friend would receive "Push notification" on his iPhone immediately. If I sent the apprequests to him, he wouldn't receive "Push notification" and just only "Facebook notification". Moveover, he needs to run the iOS Facebook app to update the data to receive the "Facebook notification".
Does anyone know this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot . And I found this http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/283253458391756 .
Moveover , my application works right after removed the parameter "notification_text" when using api "apprequests". It looks the FB demo Hackbook just misgruided me .

Answer (score 0):

For the app requests to work fully, you need to have a canvas app specified.  Otherwise the notifications won't work as expected.  From 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

> Requests are only available for Desktop Canvas apps and not websites.
>   Accepting a request will direct the user to the Canvas Page URL of the
>   app that sent the Request.

More information can also be found here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/